# Ant Design not loading icons (with Webpack)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, antd

I moved a React app from create-react-app to Webpack 5 and the UI library, Ant Design, is no longer loading the icons on components.

For several components, this is having functionality breaking effects.

#### Issue

When attempting to use a component that has an icon, it will console.log the below error message and render the component without that icon.

#### Error Message

```
warning.js:16 Warning: [@ant-design/icons] icon should be icon definiton, but got:

var LeftOutlined={icon:{tag:"svg",attrs:{viewBox:"64 64 896 896",focusable:"false"},children:[{tag:"path",attrs:{d:"M724 218.3V141c0-6.7-7.7-10.4-12.9-6.3L260.3 486.8a31.86 31.86 0 000 50.3l450.8 352.1c5.3 4.1 12.9.4 12.9-6.3v-77.3c0-4.9-2.3-9.6-6.1-12.6l-360-281 360-281.1c3.8-3 6.1-7.7 6.1-12.6z"}}]},name:"left",theme:"outlined"};export default LeftOutlined;
```

#### Webpack

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.min.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [__dirname, 'src', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.ts', '.less'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: '@svgr/webpack',
            options: {
              babel: false,
              icon: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.png|svg|jpg|gif$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

#### Babel

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [["@babel/transform-runtime"]]
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?